# Problem with my C# code shows System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32] both like and dislike

Tags: c#

I have been trying these exercises and there is one problem. Before that, I want to mention that my code is very messy but I want to clear the elephant in the room. My code is below.
Main.cs

```
namespace StackOverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var post = new Post();
 
                post.UpVote();
                post.DownVote();
 
                post.CurrentVoteValue();
 
                Console.Write("Do you want to quit? press(Y/N) : ");
                char quit= Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
 
                if (quit== 'Y' || quit == 'y')
                    break;
                else if (quit == 'N' || quit == 'n')
                    continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Post.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
 
namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Post
    {
        private string _title { get; set; }
        private string _description { get; set; }
        private DateTime _created;
        private int _like;
        private int _dislike;
        private List<int> _likeVoters;
        private List<int> _dislikeVoters;
        public Post()
        {
            Console.Write("Input title post = ");
            _title = Console.ReadLine();
 
            Console.Write("Input Description post = ");
            _description = Console.ReadLine();
 
            _created = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine("This post {0}", _created);
 
            Console.Write("Do you like this post? (Y/N) : ");
            char opinion = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
 
            if(opinion == 'Y' || opinion == 'y')
                _like++;
 
 
            else if (opinion == 'N' || opinion == 'N')
                _dislike++;
        }
 
        public List<int> UpVote()
        {
            _likeVoters = new List<int>();
            _likeVoters.Add(_like);
            return _likeVoters;
        }
 
        public List<int> DownVote()
        {
            _dislikeVoters = new List<int>();
            _dislikeVoters.Add(_dislike);
            return _dislikeVoters;
        }
 
        public void CurrentVoteValue()
        {
            var like = UpVote();
            var dislike = DownVote();
 
            Console.WriteLine(like);
            Console.WriteLine(dislike);
        }
    }
}
```

So the problem with the code is that when I run it the public void CurrentVoteValue() shows System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32] both like and dislike.

Thank you in advance to anyone who reads it.

Comment: You are trying to write and object of Type `List<int>` to the console. What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: If you want to output all ints in the list you can use `string.Join`:  `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",like));`. But it would be more useful to simply output the current value which is `_like`.

Comment: I think you want to be writing out `_like` instead of `like`. I'm not even sure why you need `like`

Comment: Thinking about it, why are you even using a list to hold a single value?

Comment: The reason i use a list is that since it's going numerous times and it always adds up i would be useful to use list.

Comment: It works to use the output the current value with _like but when the loop comes the numbers don't add up it resets back to zero any idea for that? @TimSchmelter

Comment: @Williams: What is the advantage in having a list which contains all like values? You will have something like `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,.....4711`. Why not simply storing just the last value which is `4711`?

Comment: @Williams: _"when the loop comes the numbers don't add up"_ You create a new instance of `Post`, so of course this instance is "reset" to it's default values. You have to create this instance outside of the loop.

Comment: @TimSchmelter thank you for the reminder was too stupid that i didn't think it through

Answer (score 0):

In Post.Cs, assuming you want to output the number of likes/dislikes you want to use a .Count in when outputing your list.

```
    Console.Write("Do you like this post? (Y/N) : ");
    char opinion = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

    if(opinion == 'Y' || opinion == 'y')
        _like++;


    else if (opinion == 'N' || opinion == 'N')
        _dislike++;
    }

    public List<int> UpVote()
    {
        _likeVoters = new List<int>();
        _likeVoters.Add(_like);
        return _likeVoters;
    }

    public List<int> DownVote()
    {
        _dislikeVoters = new List<int>();
        _dislikeVoters.Add(_dislike);
        return _dislikeVoters;
    }

    public void CurrentVoteValue()
    {
        var like = UpVote();
        var dislike = DownVote();

        Console.WriteLine(like.Count());
        Console.WriteLine(dislike.Count());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: As a little extra you shouldn't use a list of integers. Instead you can declare to int variables (like, dislike) and simply increment its value as you need.

Comment: Both of you're idea works but when the loop comes the numbers don't add up it resets back to zero any idea for that?

Comment: The reason that is happening is because you are creating a new instance of the class Post at the start of your loop. Every time the complier loops around the object post is instantiated, which means all the data from that class is now blank hence you getting 0s